# Getting list of bluetoooth devices ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am developing a module in which I need to get all bleutooth devices and connect the selected device. I am using this

```
blueManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central

{

  NSString *messtoshow;

    switch (central.state) {

    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"State unknown, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered off."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];
          [self.blueManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
          CBUUID *deviceInfoUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"];
        NSLog(@"connected devices ios 8 code%@  ",[blueManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[deviceInfoUUID]]);

}
```

and my bluetooth is on and connected to two devices which I can see from setting but I am not getting any device. I have checked in

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {}
```

method but it is not calling. And I know that two BLE devices is already connected to my device

Comment: Are your device Bluetooth low energy devices?

Comment: Yes my device and my connected device also BLE enabled

Comment: How is your `blueManager` property declared?  Do you get the log messages from the state delegate method?

Comment: I declared as
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *blueManager;

 and i put break point at delegate
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
it is calling randomly very rare

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please help me out.
I am struggling since 2 days

Comment: Have you tried the lightblue app to see if it can see your peripherals. I also have some code here  https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: I am not getting device in lightblue App

Comment: Make sure no other apps are connected to the device. What is the device?

Comment: one is Mac mini and other is XGPS160 gps tracker

Comment: The xgps160 isn't BLE, it is legacy Bluetooth. The Mac mini will need to be running an app that advertises a peripheral before it will show up

Comment: Is there any way to get xgps160 via bluetooth

Comment: I don't think so. Once it is paired any app that uses core location will take advantage of the gps data.  There is also a note in their FAQ that there is a bug with ios8.3 that prevents the device from working with apps

Comment: Lots of thanks to you @Paulw11 !!!!!